# Adding a line break to a custom header css style?

Tags: html, css

Newbie Q here: How can I add a linebreak in a custom header style?

```
h21 
{
    font-size: 1.52em;
    /*Equivalent of a line break here...????*/
}
```

Comment: you could do it in several ways: with a <br> element; or with a style -- padding-top:5px; after the font-size styling.

Comment: you can use margin-bootom: this will create a difference between the header and the element beneath the headers.(difference size will be depends on the pix or % passed in the style property)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant add a linebreak in a class declaration, but you can add margin-bottom or padding-bottom: -10px or similar varieties. You can use firebug to measure how high a linebreak on your page appears and use that value for padding or margin -bottom.

```
h21 {
    font-size:12.1px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `word-wrap` property. [see here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/word-wrap)

an example:

```
h21 {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

**obs**: the container element should have a width